# Redirect a specific webpage to a mobile version of that particular page

Tags: redirect, mobile

We already redirect our main site to a mobile version. However we need to redirect mobile users, after submitting the form on the mobile site (same form is used on both main site and mobile site), to a mobile thank you page.

Currently: Complete the form on mob site > submit > redirect to thank you page on main site (using the same form only allows us to redirect to one URL after submission - currently this page resides on main site).

I am guessing this will require some additional js code on the main site thank you page to detect and redirect to the mobile version of the thank you page.

It has been already been suggested we clone the form; Original for the main site and clone for mobile site. Due to data base requirements this is not a preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX Post to submit the form from the mobile page, then redirect to the thank you page.